# BufferOverflow issue

Tags: android, h.264, android-mediacodec

When I run below code I got this error **java.nio.BufferOverflowException**
I am trying to create video streaming from camera Preview in android, I get NV21 byte data from the camera and I tried convert mp4 format it.When I try this I got error When running **inputBuffer.put(data);** line, How can solve it? Can I try other method to convert byte to .mp4?

```
private void encode(byte[] data) {
    inputBuffers = mMediaCodec.getInputBuffers();
    outputBuffers = mMediaCodec.getOutputBuffers();

    int inputBufferIndex = mMediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(-1);
    if (inputBufferIndex >= 0) {
        ByteBuffer inputBuffer = inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];
        inputBuffer.clear();
        inputBuffer.put(data);
        mMediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, data.length, 0, 0);
    } else {
        return;
    }

    MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
    int outputBufferIndex = mMediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);
    Log.i(TAG, "outputBufferIndex-->" + outputBufferIndex);
    do {
        if (outputBufferIndex >= 0) {
            ByteBuffer outBuffer = outputBuffers[outputBufferIndex];
            System.out.println("buffer info-->" + bufferInfo.offset + "--"
                    + bufferInfo.size + "--" + bufferInfo.flags + "--"
                    + bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs);
            byte[] outData = new byte[bufferInfo.size];
            outBuffer.get(outData);
            try {
                if (bufferInfo.offset != 0) {
                    fos.write(outData, bufferInfo.offset, outData.length
                            - bufferInfo.offset);
                } else {
                    fos.write(outData, 0, outData.length);
                }
                fos.flush();
                Log.i(TAG, "out data -- > " + outData.length);
                mMediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, false);
                outputBufferIndex = mMediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo,
                        0);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (outputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
            outputBuffers = mMediaCodec.getOutputBuffers();
        } else if (outputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
            MediaFormat format = mMediaCodec.getOutputFormat();
        }
    } while (outputBufferIndex >= 0);
}

private void initCodec() {
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(mVideoFile, false);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        mMediaCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("video/avc");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc",
            320,
            240);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 125000);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 15);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT,
            MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 5);
    mMediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat,
            null,
            null,
            MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
    mMediaCodec.start();

}
```

Comment: Please indicate which line the exception is occurring on, and add your `MediaCodec` configuration code.

Comment: I have MediaCodec configration code I editted above,I got error this code "inputBuffer.put(data);"

Comment: Looks like you're using hardcoded dimensions (320x240). Are you sure your camera isn't supplying a larger frame? Please add your camera configuration code as well.

Comment: yes my friend my problem is this,I solved thanks,but I cannot get audio from h264 only playing video, how can I do play video with audio

Comment: You may want to ask a new question. Look for things like AAC and `MediaMuxer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MediaCodec` has been configured to use fixed dimensions, 320x240, which are apparently smaller than the camera frames being used. If the `MediaCodec` is expecting smaller frames, it will supply smaller `inputBuffers`, which leads to the `BufferOverflowException`.

To fix, configure your camera to use dimensions 320x240, or configure your `MediaCodec` dynamically based on the currently selected camera preview size.